# After how many years since its first issue, does a journal get its impact factor

Tags: journals, bibliometrics

After how many years since its first issue, does a journal from a good publication get its impact factor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Getting an impact factor is not something that depends on the duration the journal has been published**. To get an impact factor the hard part is getting indexed by Web of Science. After you are indexed, *then* getting an impact factor is something that will happen automatically. But getting indexed is not trivial; in fact it's one of the biggest challenges facing a new journal. Simply publishing issues will not do it; you need to do other things like publish in English, have peer review policies, and most importantly, generate citations from articles that are published in already-indexed journals. See the criteria [here](https://clarivate.com/essays/journal-selection-process/).

Comment: Consider a new journal from a very reputed publication that satisfies all the necessary criteria. So, how many minimum no. of  years since its first issue, does it get indexed in SCI or SCIE?

Comment: @ShiS journals don't just "get indexed", they need to apply to be indexed - see http://mjl.clarivate.com/journal-submission/